# How to always compile a cpp file with Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, g++

I have included a unix timestamp `__DATE__` in one of my cpp source files to indicate the build date of my program. Naturally with default setups it compiles the file only when I change it but now I'd like to have it always compiled. I tried to search through the project settings but it seems that this would need deeper understanding of the compiler. I'm using Eclipse with g++.

I tried to google and search for an answer but I found it difficult to find good keywords for this.

Also is there a markable difference wether I do this change for a header file instead of the source file?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a 'pre-build' step which [touch](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_touch.htm) the file (so the time stamp is modified and force to recompile the file).

Answer (score 4):

> it seems that this would need deeper understanding of the compiler.

**No, it must be done by the build system.**

A very simple-minded way of doing it is as follows. Create a single file called date.cpp with the following content and nothing else:

```
#include <string>

std::string build_time() {
    return __DATE__ " " __TIME__;
}
```

You can use it like this in some *other* source file

```
cout << "Built on " << build_time() << endl;
```

The build system keeps track of your changes and it will only recompile those source files that have changed (that are necessary to be recompiled). Since you are not changing date.cpp file, it won't recompile it. However, you can force it by right clicking on the project folder and then

*Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Build Steps > Post-build steps*

and adding the following line to the comand field on Linux:

```
rm -f <path to the Debug / Release directory>/date.o
```

where you put yours to `<path to the Debug / Release directory>`.

On Windows `del /q` seems to do the same as `rm -f`, please check.

Since we delete the generated object file date.o, the build system must rebuild it again with the current build date and time when you compile the your application.

It's likely that there are many other variants but the above is in my opinion simple enough and does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. For TASKING (based on Eclipse, so might very likely work there as well), the following worked on Windows 10: "rm -f ${ProjDirPath}\Debug\path_to_file\version.o" (without the quotes) in Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Build Steps > Pre-build steps > Command. "del" didn't work, I guess Eclipse just uses linux-alike commands internally.

Comment: @MatthiasLuh Thanks for the feedback. I don't have access to any versions of Windows, so I cannot check it myself. My original answer also indicates that it is either `rm -f` or `del /q`, so I don't think I should change the answer. Also, I think Eclipse does not use any commands: it will execute what you enter "as is". In other words, it is *your* environment in which you run Eclipse that supports `rm` but not `del`.